# my try catch.. is being weird and how do i know i am writing a file

Tags: java

I am trying to save a object of type Person to a file, and i see that when i use IOEXception both of these
 work but am not sure they are going in to a file

```
            bw.write(content);
            System.out.println(tree.next());
```

// MAKE SURE TO CLOSE OUT or otherwise it will flush
bw.close;
when i use try catch like below only one or the other works, however both IOExcetion throw and try ...catch print the tree but i am lost on how to make the program save this tree to a file

```
  public static void Save()  {
 try{
    TreeIterator<Person> tree = new TreeIterator<Person>(phoneBook);
    tree.setPreorder();


        File file = new File("BSTtree.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        while (tree.hasNext()) {

            String content = tree.next().toString();
            System.out.println(tree.next());

        //  bw.write(content);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: Give us the stacktrace please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `next()` twice on the iterator.

Store the `Person` in a temp variable to call `next` only once after having called `hasNext()`:

```
while (tree.hasNext()) {
    Person p = tree.next();
    String content = p.toString();
    System.out.println(p);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: @ClearMist I'd like to add for clearity: If the first call to next() exhausts the iterator, then the second call will throw an exception. But that should be "NoSuchElementException", not IOException.

Comment: wow Thank you!! but i tried opening the file which is BSTfile.txt i put it under project in Eclipse, but it doesn't seem to have writte it after execution

Comment: Fildor, yeap i just looked at that too thank you, but one question howcome what i printed in the console doesn't appear in the text file i wrote it to?

Comment: @ClearMist You also need to refresh the file after the execution before opening it through Eclipse

Comment: :/ still nothing, i refreshed before opening after execution